# sql query within for loop - error: expecting single string value

Tags: sql, r, for-loop

**Objective:**

I'm writing a function within R to iterate over each element of a defined vector to perform the following tasks:

1. query tables within snowflake - each element in the vector is the name of a table.
2. if the table exists perform task set A, if it does not then perform task set B

So I'm trying to compile a conditional statement within a 'for' loop.

**Problem Statement:**

However, I'm struggling to understand why the following piece of code results in the error below.  I'm missing something obvious it seems but it's not obvious to me unfortunately.  It's failing when I simply test point #1 (the sql query).

```
for (package_id in vec_package_id2)

  {

  sql_query_check_table   <-      glue_sql(
                                            "SHOW TABLES LIKE {package_id_param}"
                                        
                                            , package_id_param = package_id
                                            , .con = connection
                                          )

  val_check_table         <-      dbGetQuery(connection, sql_query_check_table)
  
  }
```

**Result:**

I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=2].

There are two elements within the vector 'vec_package_id2' so it's obviously pulling in both element but the loop should be taking each element independently(?)

vec_package_id2 looks as follows:

| pkg_id |
| --- |
| 5854 |
| 4345 |

**Expected Result:**

I'm expecting it to iterate over each vector

I want then to be able to utilise the result of 'val_check_table' within a conditional ('if') statement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I may have fixed my own issue here, the vector I state is not actually a vector but a single column 'data frame' that I'm passing in.  I have added a pull() to the vec_package_id2 and now the 'for' loop performs as required.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, it appears that what I thought was a vector I was passing in was actually a single column data frame (brain not engaged!).

Numerous ways of amending this I appreciate but I utilised the following:

```
vec_package_id2 <- vec_package_id %>% pull(pkg_id)
```

the 'pkg_id' is the column name.  This creates a vector and all works as intended.